# Module aliasing in Julia

Tags: module, julia

In python you can do something like this to let you use a shortened module name:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

From then on you can refer to `tf`, instead of having to type `tensorflow` everywhere.

Is something like this possible in Juila?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yep, you can just assign the module to a new name.

```
import JSON
const J = JSON

J.print(Dict("Hello, " => "World!"))
```

I highly recommend to use the `const` because otherwise there will be a performance penalty. (With the `const`, there is no performance penalty.)

Comment: See also https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1255. This will probably have a better syntax at some point.

Answer (score 9):

Julia now supports [renaming with as](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm pushing the practical snippet @Alan don't mentioned:

- At `MyMod.jl`:

```
module MyModule

plus(x, y) = x + y
myfield = 0

end
```

- At `Main.jl`:

```
# Only if you're including the module from another file.
include("MyMod.jl")

import .MyModule as mymod

println(mymod.myfield)
println(mymod.plus(1, 1))
```

Main resources:

- Docs https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/.
- Issue https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1255.
- Commit https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/40fee86878068d5c7c833655b7637820fb2cba33.