# How to use package in Julia without importing it?

Tags: julia

If you write it imports all bunch of methods into the current scope.

```
using Plots
plot(rand(5,5))
```

I need only one method, is it possible to write the same code but without `using` or importing anything, I don't want to pollute the current scope with `Plots` exports and don't mind to prefix it with package name every time I use it.

```
Plots.plot(rand(5,5))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`import`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#import) will bring a module into scope without any of its exported names. You can still use qualified names to reference names within the imported module:

```
import Plots
Plots.plot(rand(5,5))
```

To avoid using the qualified name, you can create a binding to a new name:

```
const plot_from_plots = Plots.plot
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Julia website](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/index.html) you should be able to do:

```
using Plots: plot
```

Which will only bring `plot()` in scope

---

See [Module aliasing in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104130/module-aliasing-in-julia) for how to create an alias for the method

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it's possible to import it into the current scope with the different name? Like `plot_from_pots`? I don't want the `plot` method in current scope because there's another method with the same name.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104130/module-aliasing-in-julia) is the closest you could get, which wouldn't solve your problem unfortunately

Comment: You can do myplot(args... ;kwargs...) = Plots.plot(args...,kwargs...)

Comment: Or more simply: `import Plots; const myplot = Plots.plot` (edit: as David shows in the other answer).

Comment: That does bring the name `Plots` into scope though.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other suggestions; I wrote a package ([`ImportMacros`](https://github.com/fredrikekre/ImportMacros.jl)) which lets you import functions with other names without bringing anything else into scope:

```
julia> using ImportMacros

julia> @import Plots.plot as plt

julia> plt
plot (generic function with 3 methods)
```

so `Plots.plot` is available as `plt`, yet `Plots` is undefined:

```
julia> Plots
ERROR: UndefVarError: Plots not defined
```