# How to detach a package without restarting

Tags: julia, julia-pkg

Ref: [docs](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/repl/#package-commands) for `Pkg`

I want to compare two methods with the same name from two different packages in the same session/script. To avoid name collision, I would like to **negate** `using` (i.e. "undo" / "reverse"). Something like what [detach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979917/how-to-unload-a-package-without-restarting-r) does for `R`.

```
using PackageOne
some_method()

undo using PackageOne  # <-- negate `using PackageOne` without restarting
using PackageTwo
some_method()  # name collision avoided here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot detach a package that is already loaded in some module AFAICT. What you can do is wrap your code using these methods in a module like this:

```
module Test1
    using PackageOne
    some_method()
end

module Test2
    using PackageTwo
    some_method()
end
```

another approach would be:

```
using PackageOne
using PackageTwo

methods = [PackageOne.some_method, PackageTwo.some_method]

function test(some_method)
    # here use some_method
end

for method in methods
    test(method)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Bogumił! How about reloading a module after edits? No problem with some globals left behind? Typically this need arises when testing what happens if a method uses `Test1.some_method()` vs `Test2.some_method()`. A bit tedious to type. In some cases it will be easier to restart Julia. If I could `import as` (there was talk of introducing that feature, I wonder what happened), I could just do `A.some_method()` and `B.some_method()` and avoid the modules while still having to prefix.

Comment: Actually, you can do "import aliasing" in the simplest way. `A = PackageOne`, and `B = PackageTwo`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104130/module-aliasing-in-julia  (not great if you want to use variables `A` and `B` for some other purpose of course)

Comment: For reloading module after edits use Revise.jl. Import aliasing is a different thing. I thought you have a code you cannot modify that calls `some_method` function and you get ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used `Revise.jl`. Will do. There are several use cases. Say you have a method that goes through several generations as you update a package. At some point you want to compare their action. You write a script where you pull them one by one and have the results within the same script. So my first idea was to switch the `using` or `import` on and off as the need arises. But it seems like  it'll be easier to create a list of the methods and then pull them in a loop: then only their position in the list matters, not their actual name. Can you create modules in a loop easily?

Comment: I will add another approach that fits looping well.

Comment: Your edit looks great. I really like this second approach. Thank you so much! :-)